# What is the difference in giving negative value to insetLeft instead of using insetRight

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have looked into InsetDrawables examples in which some of the snippets like below using negative insetLeft instead of using insetRight. Is there any difference ?

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#999" />

        <gradient
            android:centerY="0.0"
            android:endColor="#BBB"
            android:gradientRadius="500"
            android:startColor="#DDD"
            android:type="radial" >
        </gradient>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <inset
        android:insetBottom="30dp"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetRight="30dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp" >
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#DDD" />

            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </inset>
</item>
```

What is the difference between using inset drawable v/s top, bottom, left, right attributes to the item like below ?

```
<item android:bottom="30dp" android:right="30dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#DDD" />

            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
</item>
```

Any explanation w.r.t insetDrawables would be great :)

Comment: you cannot use `insetLeft` instead of using `insetRight`, they are different things

Comment: @pskink Can you please explain or direct me to a resource with good explanation?

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.java#1809